# Accessing members of a custom data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Say I have the following custom data type and function in Haskell:

```
data Person = Person { first_name :: String, 
                       last_name :: String,
                       age :: Int 
                     } deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

If I want to create a function `print_age` to print a Person's age, like so: `print_age (Person "John" "Smith" 21)` , how would I write `print_age` to access the age parameter? I'm an Object Oriented guy, so I'm out of my element here. I'm basically looking for the equivalent of Person.age.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Function application is prefix, so `age person` would correspond to the `person.age()` common in OOP languages. The `print_age` function could be defined pointfree by function composition

```
print_age = print . age
```

or point-full

```
print_age person = print (age person)
```

Answer (score 26):

This is called record syntax, [LYAH has a good section on it](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax).

When a datatype is defined with records, Haskell automatically defines functions with the same name as the record to act as accessors, so in this case `age` is the accessor for the age field (it has type `Person -> Int`), and similarly for `first_name` and `last_name`.

These are normal Haskell functions and so are called like `age person` or `first_name person`.

Comment: In Frege (Haskell for the JVM) a record introduces a namespace, so you would write ```Person.age person```. On the other hand, Frege allows writing ```person.age```, just like in OO.

Comment: As a complete (!) newbee, I'm finding the namespace clutter produced by records to be ugly and frustrating.  The Frege syntax is attractive and, iiuc, avoids this problem.

Comment: Ah, I see I am not alone:
https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/NameSpacing

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the `age` function mentioned in other answers, it is sometimes convenient to use pattern matching.

```
print_age Person { age = a } = {- the a variable contains the person's age -}
```

There is a pretty innocuous extension that allows you to skip the naming bit:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}
print_age Person { age } = {- the age variable contains the person's age -}
```

...and another, viewed with varying degrees of distrust by various community members, which allows you to even skip saying which fields you want to bring into scope:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
print_age Person { .. } = {- first_name, last_name, and age are all defined -}
```