# How can I access the members of a custom made class if they are not named?

Tags: haskell

I've got a predefined class:

```
data Wave = Wave [Double] deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I want to use the function 'map' with the class, and so I have to access the [Double]-value. But I do not know how.

I looked here: [Accessing members of a custom data type in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115623/accessing-members-of-a-custom-data-type-in-haskell), but that didn't answer my question, as I can't change (or name parameters of) the class.

I tried to write:

```
waveToDoubleList :: Wave -> [Double]
    (Wave wave) = wave
```

Comment: This is not a class; it is a datatype. Furthermore, you cannot change the contents of that, since all data in Haskell is immutable. It's not entirely clear what you're asking here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to include the *function name*:

```
waveToDoubleList :: Wave -> [Double]
waveToDoubleList (Wave wave) = wave
----------------
```

Now it should work.

`(Wave wave)` is known as a *pattern*. This function works by *pattern matching*.

`Wave` is used in two roles: as a data constructor, or pattern name; and as the type's name.

When starting learning Haskell, you might want to use separate names for these roles:

```
data Wave = MkWave [Double] deriving (Show, Eq)

waveToDoubleList :: Wave -> [Double]
waveToDoubleList (MkWave wave) = wave
```

Here `Wave` is a type; we create values of this type with `MkWave` data constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You can name parameters of your datatype very easily. For example

```
data Wave = Wave { waveContents :: [Double] } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

This produces a function `waveContents :: Wave -> [Double]`. You may also construct data in the same way: `Wave [1.2, 2.3] :: Wave`.

Here is an example of how to use this:

```
λ myWave = Wave [1.2, 2.3, 3.4]
λ waveContents myWave
[1.2, 2.3, 3.4]
λ Wave $ map (+1) $ waveContents myWave
Wave [2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
```

Comment: this is known as *record syntax*